# Cleint Side Javascript To Full Stack Developer Using node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, server-side, angular-fullstack

i am working now as a client side developer with javascript/html/css for about 5 years, and for those past 5 years my main focus was on Client Side development in a browser environment. I want to proceed to full stack development using node.js on the server side, but the problem is that im lacking server side knowledge about server side communication.

I was wondering if there are people here who made the transformation to full stack developers from Javascript client side, and what usefull tips you can share with me.

I would really apreciate recomandations on books you know about this transformation from client side to full stack, or even video curses, since i didnt really find any.

Comment: Question on Stackoverflow usually contain:
    a specific programming problem, or
    a software algorithm, or
    software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
    a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development 
This question seems too open ended, and will not be easily answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn everything about REST web service on server side, ssh protocol and take a look at the expressJs framework